# Output comments columns instead of the column names

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the table and comments to the columns of this table in **all_col_comments** table. How can I instead column names in my table output the column comment from all_col_comments in select query?

example:

```
SELECT column1 AS 'comment for column1 from all_col_comments table'
     , column2 AS 'comment for column2 from all_col_comments table',
  FROM my_table;
```

**Question V2** what i want to do

```
SQL> create table myTable(
  2    id           NUMBER(2),
  3    value        NUMBER(6,2)
  4  )
  5  /
Table created.

SQL>
SQL> -- prepare data
SQL> insert into myTable(ID,  value)values (1,9)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into myTable(ID,  value)values (2,2.11)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from myTable
  2  /

        ID      VALUE
---------- ----------
         1          9
         2       2.11

2 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> COMMENT ON COLUMN myTable.id IS
  2  'id stores the id';

Comment created.

SQL> COMMENT ON COLUMN myTable.value IS
  2  'value stores the some comment for value';

Comment created.
```

Then I need to do some select and get this

```
SQL>
SQL> select ??? ...

id stores the id      value stores the some comment for value
      ----------                                   ----------
               1                                            9
               2                                         2.11

    2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Column comments are really only intended for documentation purposes.

Comment: Basically you need pivot to display col. values as columns. But think how long your comments are to use instead of columns. Can you imagine the length of your output? Drop the idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do what you are asking without dynamic SQL.  There's no way to parameterise the column aliases (the bits after `AS`), so you will have to build the SQL string up using concatenation.

As you are building up SQL strings using concatenation, you'll need to think how to mitigate against SQL injection.  (The risk would be low; if you've got the permissions to change a comment on a database table, you've probably got enough permissions to access the database directly without needing to construct suitably malicious column comments.)  At the very least, your SQL string will need to surround column aliases with `"` characters (not `'` as in your question) and before concatenating a column comment into the SQL string, you must verify that the comment does not contain the `"` character.

**EDIT**: from your comment it seems you're using Perl to talk to the database.  The following is an untested sketch which hopefully shows a way to build the SQL string.  I'll leave it up to you to fill in the gaps:

```perl
# The list of columns to select from the table.
# Must exactly match the names of columns returned from user_col_comments
my @columns = qw/COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4/;

# Are we adding the first column?
my $first = 1;

my $sql = 'SELECT ';

# Hash that maps column names to comments.
my %commenthash = ();

# TODO query user_col_comments and add to %commenthash the column names and comments.

for my $col (@columns) {

    my $comment = $commenthash{$col};

    unless (defined $comment) {
        # Use the column name if no comment was found.
        $comment = $col;
    }

    if ($comment =~ /"/) {
        die "can't use double-quotes in column comment: $comment";
    }

    # Add separating comma if this is not the first column.
    $sql .= ', ' if !$first;

    $sql .= qq!"$col" AS "$comment"!;

    $first = 0;
}

$sql .= ' FROM my_table';

# TODO execute SQL.
```

Note that you will need to query the database twice: once to get the column comments and once to get the actual data.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my example **'** is not SQL symbol, this is just for example. I'll use **q'!comment for column1 from all_col_comments table!'** in my select, but i don't how build SQL query.

Comment: Thanks. See version 2 of my question.

Comment: @a1b0r: the short answer is that there's no 'easy' way of doing what you want.  You certainly can't achieve that with SQL alone.  Quite simply, there's no way to tell Oracle 'use the comment on this column as the alias' without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for help. Maybe worth write to Tom? Who know, maybe it's be in version 12 or 13 :)

Answer (score 0):

[You can get the comments on your columns using user_col_comments](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0600__System-Tables-Data-Dictionary/GettingColumnComments.htm).

```
SELECT *
FROM user_col_comments
WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

Answer (score -1):

Using dynamic query (not tested):

```
begin
 s := ' select ';
 for i in ( select column_name, column_comment from user_tables where table_name = 'MyTable' )
 loop
  s := i.column_name ||' AS ' ||'"'|| i.column_comment || '", '; 
 end loop;
s := s || ' from ' || 'MyTable';

dbms_output.put_line( 'SQL: ' || s ); -- SHOW
execute immediate ... -- execute
end;
/
```

Comment: i know how to add an alice but in my case i need alice as a column comment...columns comment oracle stores in user_col_comments table

Comment: Just changed answer, didn't get it that way at 1st.